# How to set the start time of MediaClips in c# MediaComposition?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP Desktop application in which I use a MediaComposition with multiple images. The problem is that all images have a specific time to appear and a duration. How do I set the start time for each MediaClip?

```
MediaComposition mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();

var clipCover = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(stgCover, tmsCompositionDuration);
mediaComposition.Clips.Add(clip);
```

Comment: reading the documentation it seems that as long as you're getting each tmsCompositionDuration right as you're loading clips into the mediacomposition you don't need to do anything else. Could you check it out on your end ? I'd be intersted to know what you got.

Comment: @Mekap I fixed the start time problem for each clip, but now I have another problem. I can't add more than five clips in MediaComposition. Do you have any idea how to solve this? When I try to include more than five clips, MediaComposition craches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set the start time of MediaClips in c# MediaComposition?

Currently, there is not such api to set start time for the `MediaClip`, you just make image clip with specific duration and insert it into `mediaComposition` list. for the start time, you need calculate it manually (*previous clips duration summation*).

For your scenario,  you could use  `MediaClip.CreateFromColor`  to make empty color frame  and insert it into specific index to update the clip's start time.

for more detail, please refer to this [Media compositions and editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing) tutorial.

Comment: I fixed the start time problem for each clip, but now I have another problem. I can't add more than five clips in MediaComposition. Do you have any idea how to solve this? When I try to include more than five clips, MediaComposition craches.

Comment: Please post it in the new thread with code, I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Overlays:
Because overlays are stacked on top of each other instead of being played sequentially, all overlays start playback at the beginning of the composition by default. To cause an overlay to be begin playback at another time, set the Delay property to the desired time offset ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing#add-an-overlay-to-a-composition))